# When is it required to use @JoinColumn annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I understand that @JoinColumn is used for managed association. But if we have referential integrity in place in place in the database, then do we still require to use @JoinColumn annotation for the fields (the foreign key field in the class). Suppose I have 2 tables - author, and book. Is it required for me to have @JoinColumn annotation for book_aut_id field in the entity class? Because even if I don't use the @JoinColumn annotation, the referential integrity will still be maintained.

```
create table mydb.author(
aut_id int auto_increment,
aut_name varchar(20),
constraint author_pk primary key (aut_id)
);
```

```
create table mydb.book(
book_id int auto_increment,
book_title varchar(20),
book_aut_id int,
constraint book_pk primary key (book_id),
constraint book_fk foreign key (book_aut_id) references author(aut_id)
);
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private int bookId;
    
    @Column(name = "book_title")
    private String bookTitle;
    
    @Column(name = "book_aut_id")
//  @OneToOne
//  @JoinColumn(name="aut_id")
    private int bookAutId;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
@Data
public class Author {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "aut_id")
    private int authorId;
    
    @Column(name = "aut_name")
    private String authorName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is Not required but just if you want to rename the foreign key in database
because by default in this case your foreign key in Book table is -> bookAutId
if you add Annotation
@Column(name = "book_aut_id")
will be book_aut_id